# iOS Tests target cannot access target pods

Tags: ios, unit-testing, cocoapods

I made a test target for my app. It has dependencies like

```
import XCTest
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import RxBlocking
@testable import MyApp
```

And my Podfile looks like

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

def shared_pods
    pod 'RxSwift',          '~> 2.0'
    pod 'RxCocoa',          '~> 2.0'
end

target 'Mobium-ios' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'Mobium-ios-tests' do
    shared_pods
    pod 'RxBlocking',       '~> 2.0'
    pod 'RxTests',          '~> 2.0'
end
```

However, in my test I cannot import RxBlocking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Build for testing' solved the issue.

Comment: can you explain ?

Comment: I don't remember but I think I needed to select test configuration and/or try to build tests specifically